Convergence of Sequence of Extended Real-Valued Fuctions
Definition:
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real-valued functions on A. We say that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $A$ if $\forall x\in A$ and $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists $N:=N(x,\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ we have
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon.$$
Is this definition of convergence of sequence of real-valued functions just the same for convergence of sequence of extended real-valued functions?
So based on the comments given, basically if we're not using the general definition, there are two definitions, one for finite limits and one for infinite limits of sequence of extended real-valued functions.
Finite Limits: $\{_\}$ converges to $$ pointwise on $$ if $\forall  \in $ and $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists $:=(,\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ then
$$|_()−()|<\epsilon.$$
Infinite Limits: $\{_\}$ converges to $\infty$ if $\forall x\in A$ and $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ we have that $f_n(x)\geq c$. Is this correct?

Please be more explicit: edit your post to formalize both definitions you have in mind.

Presumably when you say that a sequence of functions with values in the extended real numbers converges you want to use the general definition of convergence of sequences of functions with values in a topological space $(X,\tau)$, i.e. $f_n:A\to X$ converges pointwise to $f$ if for all $x\in A$ and for all neighbourhoods $U\ni f(x)$ there is some $N$ such that, for all $m\ge N$, $f_m(x)\in U$.

When $f(x)=\infty$ how do you possibly write $|f_n(x)-f(x)|,?$  What is the most natural way to define a neighbourhood of $+\infty,?$

Thank you for having edited your post to formalize the first definition you have in mind. What about the second one? (the one about which you are asking whether it is "just the same")

Thanks everyone, so basically if we're not using the general definition, there are two definitions, one for finite limits and one for infinite limits of sequence of extended real-valued functions.
Finite Limits: ${f_n}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $A$ if $\forall x\in A$ and $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists $N:=N(x,\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ then
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon.$$
Infinite Limits: ${f_n}$ converges to $\infty$ if $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ we have that $f_n\geq c$.
Is this correct?

Yes but better put it in your post than in comment. And do not repost https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4996484
